# Receive the text after tag

Tags: r, rvest

This provides the text inside h1 tag

```
library(rvest)
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("<h1> Title </h1> keep me here <h1>not </h1> or <h2> else</h2>","also not here <h1> but</h1> here also")
rawHTML <- paste(df1$text[1], collapse="\n")
rawHTML %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text()
```

What should someone add to the command to receive whatever is after the tag h1 with text Title?

Example output:
keep me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `text` is string you can use `regex` to extract the data that you need.

```
stringr::str_extract(df1$text, '(?<=Title </h1>\\s).*(?=\\s<h1>)')
#[1] "keep me here" NA
```

You can also use `str_match` without lookbehind and lookahead regex which might be simpler.

```
stringr::str_match(df1$text, 'Title </h1>\\s(.*)\\s<h1>')[, 2]
```

Comment: Thank is it possible to make it using rvest?

Comment: I was trying initially with `rvest` but I am not aware of functions in `rvest` which allow you to select nodes based on text in previous nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` we can use `regmatches/gregexpr`

```
with(df1, trimws(sapply(regmatches(text,
    gregexpr("(?<=Title </h1> )[^<]+", text, perl = TRUE)), `[`, 1)))
#[1] "keep me here" NA
```